# Pipe and sockets remain open after streaming http response in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, http, stream

I'm attempting to stream data from a http response to a cloud storage provider in an internal service.

```
const response = await request<Readable>({
  headers: httpOpts?.headers,
  data: httpOpts?.data,
  url,
  method,
  responseType: 'stream',
});

const blob = this.bucket.file(path);

await pipeline(
  response.stream,
  blob.createWriteStream({
    resumable: false,
    metadata: {
      contentType,
    },
  }),
);
```

Which works great, except I notice during running integration tests on this code that there are open handles (A Pipe and some sockets) even after it's completed (I'll add them at the end).

These remain open for ~30 seconds after the file has finished streaming to it's destination.

- I've tried `.end()` / `.destroy()` on both the readstream and the writestream
- I've checked `close` and `end` events are called on the readstream
- I've tried using `AbortController` to kill it.
- I've tried specifying a httpsAgent and `destroy()`ing that
- I've tried explicitly creating a httpsAgent with `keep-alive: false` and sending `Connection: close`

I'm all out of ideas.

If I stream a GET request from elsewhere, the problem does not occur, so I'm guessing the server I'm reading from is holding the connection open in some way, but that is beyond my control.

Output of `process._getActiveHandles()`

````
        Pipe {
          pendingHandle: null,
          sockets: { got: {}, send: {} },
          buffering: false,
          [Symbol(kJSONBuffer)]: '',
          [Symbol(kStringDecoder)]: StringDecoder {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            [Symbol(kNativeDecoder)]: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 01>
          }
        },
        <ref *1> Socket {
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: null,
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
            length: 0,
            pipes: [],
            flowing: null,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: false,
            constructed: true,
            sync: true,
            needReadable: false,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            destroyed: false,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrainWriters: null,
            multiAwaitDrain: false,
            readingMore: false,
            dataEmitted: false,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null,
            readable: false,
            [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
          },
          _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd] },
          _eventsCount: 1,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            finalCalled: false,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: false,
            ended: false,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: true,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            afterWriteTickInfo: null,
            buffered: [],
            bufferedIndex: 0,
            allBuffers: true,
            allNoop: true,
            pendingcb: 0,
            constructed: true,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
          },
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: null,
          _server: null,
          _type: 'pipe',
          fd: 1,
          _isStdio: true,
          destroySoon: [Function: destroy],
          _destroy: [Function: dummyDestroy],
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: Pipe { [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1] },
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
        },
        <ref *2> Socket {
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: null,
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
            length: 0,
            pipes: [],
            flowing: null,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: false,
            constructed: true,
            sync: true,
            needReadable: false,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            destroyed: false,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrainWriters: null,
            multiAwaitDrain: false,
            readingMore: false,
            dataEmitted: false,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null,
            [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
          },
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {
            end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
            pause: [Function (anonymous)]
          },
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            finalCalled: false,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: false,
            ended: true,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: true,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            afterWriteTickInfo: null,
            buffered: [],
            bufferedIndex: 0,
            allBuffers: true,
            allNoop: true,
            pendingcb: 0,
            constructed: true,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            writable: false,
            [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
          },
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: null,
          _server: null,
          fd: 0,
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 6,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: Pipe { reading: false, [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *2] },
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
        },
        <ref *3> Socket {
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: null,
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
            length: 0,
            pipes: [],
            flowing: null,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: false,
            constructed: true,
            sync: true,
            needReadable: false,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            destroyed: false,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrainWriters: null,
            multiAwaitDrain: false,
            readingMore: false,
            dataEmitted: false,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null,
            readable: false,
            [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
          },
          _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd] },
          _eventsCount: 1,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 16384,
            finalCalled: false,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: false,
            ended: false,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: true,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            afterWriteTickInfo: null,
            buffered: [],
            bufferedIndex: 0,
            allBuffers: true,
            allNoop: true,
            pendingcb: 0,
            constructed: true,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            emitClose: false,
            autoDestroy: true,
            errored: null,
            closed: false,
            closeEmitted: false,
            [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
          },
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: null,
          _server: null,
          _type: 'pipe',
          fd: 2,
          _isStdio: true,
          destroySoon: [Function: destroy],
          _destroy: [Function: dummyDestroy],
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 7,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: Pipe { [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *3] },
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
        }
      ]```
````

Answer (score 0):

I used **worker_threads** for requesting data and when request gets completed, I used `process.exit()` in worker to kill it so I have no lingering TCP socket connections anymore. **child_process fork**  can also be used but **worker_threads** is more recent nodejs feature and supports initial data to work with.

My main script ------

```
import { Worker } from "node:worker_threads"
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join as pathJoin } from 'path';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

async function checkNet() {

  let workerPath = pathJoin(__dirname, "./worker1.mjs")
  let worker1 = new Worker(workerPath, {
    workerData: {
      url: 'https://www.example.com/',
    }
  });

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    worker1.on('message', function (response) {
      if (response && response.includes("Example Domain")) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        resolve(false)
      }
    });
  })
}

console.log(await checkNet())
```

My worker script ------

```
import got from 'got';
import { workerData, parentPort } from "node:worker_threads"

let response
try {

  response = await got(workerData.url, {
    timeout: { request: 15000 },
  })
} catch (err) {
  parentPort.postMessage(false);
  process.exit()
}
parentPort.postMessage(response.body);
if (response?.request?.socket) {
  response.request.socket.end();
  response.request.socket.destroy();
}

process.exit()
```